# Excel stops responding after VBA sets calculation mode following deletion of OLEObjects and hiding of rows

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have a large VBA/Excel project `.xlsm` file that has all of a sudden begun to stop responding (am forced to force quit Excel) when I click the Remove Row button that calls my `RemoveComparison` sub. The strange thing is that the sub occasionally works (and has worked in the past). It is as if Excel sometimes maxes out on memory when this `RemoveComparison` gets called and other times it does not. The problem goes away if I comment out `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` in the last line. When `RemoveComparison` does work, however, it takes about 2 full seconds to complete since I believe the hiding of rows or maybe the deleting of the `OLEObjects` triggers a large recalculation on other sheets when I set calculation mode back to `xlAutomatic`.

Does anyone spot what could be causing Excel to stop responding?

Here is a screenshot of the Workbook. The Remove Row button calls the sub `RemoveComparison()` that deletes `ComboBoxManagerComparison7` in this case (the one with S&P 500) and also deletes `Comparison7CheckBox` before hiding the cells (which contain formulas referencing other sheets). If the Remove Row works like it did before, clicking the button a second time would remove Comparison6, etc.

[image: Screenshot]

```
 Sub RemoveComparison()
        Application.Calculation = xlManual
        Dim CurrentNumberOfComparisons As Integer

    With Sheets("Manager")
        'get current number of comparisons (to determine which ComboBox, etc. to remove)
        CurrentNumberOfComparisons = .Range("NumberOfComparisons").Value

        If CurrentNumberOfComparisons = 1 Then
            MsgBox ("Min 1 comparison")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim ComboBoxName As String
        'determine name of ComboBox to remove
        ComboBoxName = "ComboBoxManagerComparison" & CurrentNumberOfComparisons

        Call DeleteComboBox(ComboBoxName, Sheets("Manager"))

        #If DEBUGREMOVECOMPARISON Then
            Debug.Print "Deleted ComboBox"
        #End If

        Dim CheckBoxName As String
        'determine name of CheckBox to remove
        CheckBoxName = "Comparison" & CurrentNumberOfComparisons & "CheckBox"
        Call DeleteCheckBox(CheckBoxName, Sheets("Manager"))

        #If DEBUGREMOVECOMPARISON Then
            Debug.Print "Deleted CheckBox"
        #End If

        Dim ComparisonCellToHideNamedRange As String
        'determine which cells to hide
        ComparisonCellToHideNamedRange = "selectedManagerComparison" & CurrentNumberOfComparisons & "Name"

        Dim ComparisonCellToHide As Range

        Set ComparisonCellToHide = .Range(ComparisonCellToHideNamedRange)

        Range(Rows(ComparisonCellToHide.row), Rows(ComparisonCellToHide.row + 3)).Hidden = True

        'update current number of comparisons
        .Range("NumberOfComparisons").Value = CurrentNumberOfComparisons - 1

        #If DEBUGREMOVECOMPARISON Then
            Debug.Print "Success"
        #End If

    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub

Sub DeleteComboBox(ComboBoxName As String, Sheet As Worksheet)

With Sheet
    .OLEObjects(ComboBoxName).Delete
End With

End Sub

Sub DeleteCheckBox(CheckBoxName As String, Sheet As Worksheet)

    With Sheet
        .OLEObjects(CheckBoxName).Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Still unclear why the switch from `xlManual` back to `xlAutomatic` in the sub leads to Not Responding, but if I comment out the last line of the sub `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` and manually click Formulas->Calculation Options->Automatic, the entire worksheet is recalculated even if no cells are edited. I understand that hiding cells causes a recalculation, but should hiding a row cause the recalculation of the whole worksheet (even when the hidden row has no dependents)?

**EDIT**: Excel stops crashing if I move the ComboBoxes and CheckBoxes to another part of the sheet rather than deleting them in the sub. I am not sure why the deletion of these OLEObjects caused Excel enter not responding.

Comment: VBA only has 1 thread to do its thing - the main/UI thread. "not responding" only means "I'm busy running your code, I can't handle WM messages right now - I'll get back to you ASAP". If you want to keep Excel responsive, you need to allow WM message to pipe through by sprinkling `DoEvents` at strategic spots in your code. Note that doing this will allow the user to change the `ActiveSheet` while your code is running, which means unqualified `Range` calls might start working off a different sheet than what your code is assuming. Same with unqualified `Sheets` referring to `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Nothing to do with memory

Comment: If I comment out `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` and click Remove Row, the sub occurs instantaneously. If I then manually click Formulas->Calculation Options-> Automatic, it takes ~7 seconds to calculate but I do not enter not responding. How would `DoEvents` help if the problem is on one line?

Comment: Eh, I didn't really read your code - typically "not responding" occurs when VBA code runs a loop that repeatedly accesses a worksheet. Indeed, there's not much to do for a single statement. Assigning `Application.Calculation` will trigger a recalc; if that recalc takes ~7 seconds either you bite the bullet and wait it out, or review your formulas and make *them* more efficient: the performance issue isn't with the VBA code, it's with the formulas. Charles Williams (Excel MVP) has an add-in ("FastExcel") that can help with that.

Comment: What I don't understand is if I choose to wait it out, I hit "Not Responding" that goes on for far more than 7 seconds (if it ever finishes). But when I don't put the conversion to Automatic in the sub and do it myself it only takes 7 seconds. Why is behavior different when the calculation mode conversion is in the sub?

Comment: One thing that could cause this, is if this `RemoveComparison` procedure is invoked from a `Worksheet.Calculate` event handler, making it indirectly recursive /re-entrant.

Comment: I don't think that's going on here because the button sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. The Remove Row button is the only thing that calls `RemoveComparison`.

Comment: Not expecting much, but you could try moving the concern of dealing with calculation mode out of the procedure and into its caller. Also consider toggling `Application.EnableEvents`.

Comment: So I've created `Sub RemoveComparisonB()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
RemoveComparison
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub` and set the Macro for the button to be `RemoveComparisonB` and not `RemoveComparison`. Removal seems to take about 2 seconds now and so far have not been able to get it to crash. Let me keep testing. EDIT: Nevermind, got it to crash.